# How to Install JSSOR Slider?

Tags: installation, jssor

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I added the JS script code per usual, added those two .js files to directory. Added HTML to specified location. The two images show both at the same time underneath each other, so the HTML is fine I know. Something wrong with the input of the code, either an error or issue with the installation. Is there anything that needs to be modified

```
**HTML:** 

<+div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

**JS:**

<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Define an array of slideshow transition code
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 1},
        {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 2}
        ];
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                    $ShowLink: true
                }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either jssor.slider.min.js or jssor.slider.mini.js.

Please remove the following code from your page then.

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```